# Is there a better way to dissoc a head or tail range from a sorted-map?

Tags: clojure

In Java, with a `java.util.SortedMap<Long,Object>`, we can do something like:

```
sortedMap.headSet(13).clear()
```

to get rid of all the elements with keys < 13. I don't see anything similar in clojure.core for clojure's `(sorted-map)` (which I think is always a `clojure.lang.PersistentTreeMap`). The best I've come up with is something like this:

```
(let [clear-up-to 13
      sm (sorted-map 1 "aye" 2 "bee" 13 "em" 14 "en")]
      clear-keys (take-while #(< % clear-up-to) (keys sm))
  (apply dissoc sm clear-keys))
```

Am I missing something simpler?

Comment: Clojure data structure are immutable and hence your approach is right. Even if there was inbuilt core function for such thing it would have used a similar approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dissoc is the best you can do, but the `take-while` step should be replaced with `subseq` or `rsubseq`, as appropriate.

Comment: Agreed `(apply dissoc sm (map key (subseq sm < 13)))` is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a more efficient solution in general for the built in sorted-map though using java.util.SortedMap is completely reasonable in many situations. Especially so if you make it into a persistent map after chopping it.

For what it's worth this can also be written with `reduce`:

```
user> my-sorted-map
{2 1, 4 3, 6 5, 8 7}

user>  (reduce dissoc my-sorted-map (take-while #(< % 5) (keys my-sorted-map)))
{6 5, 8 7}
```

though this is mostly a matter of taste. Your example is fine as well.

Comment: I haven't checked to see if PersistentTreeMap optimizes it, but I prefer once call to dissoc with many keys, so all those intermediate maps don't have to be created.